# Marking a directory as a source root in CLion

Tags: clion

In PyCharm, we can mark a directory as a [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-structure-dialog.html#969d3106). How can I do the same in CLion? I'm trying to get CLion to recognize my python import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason the "Mark Directory as" option will only present itself in CLion if a `CMakeLists.txt` file exists. By adding a barebones cmake file, the "Mark Directory as" option became available, and I was able to use that interface to mark directories as a source root. See [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7800097853202-Marking-Directory-as-a-python-source-root-) for details.